# Which Standard Differential Equation Does this Simplify to?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:
$$x^2 y'' + 2x y' + \left(\ell[\ell+1] + \epsilon x^2 - x^3\right)y = 0.$$
Can this differential equation be brought into one of the standard forms? I know it can't be turned into a Bessel equation. Is it a [Generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function), or do I have to turn all the way to the [Meijer G-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function)? If either of those, what are the extra parameters that need to be fed into $_p F_q\left[\begin{array}{c}
a_1,\ldots,a_p \\
b_1,\ldots,b_q
\end{array}; x\right]$ or $G^{m,n}_{p,q} \left(\left.\begin{array}{c}
a_1,\ldots,a_p \\
b_1,\ldots,b_q
\end{array} \right| x\right)$?

For context: this is the equation you get when you consider a time-independent Schödinger equation of a particle in an infinite conical well ($V(r) \propto r$) in 3 dimensions.

Comment: See the answer to the [physics version of this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297131/eigenstates-of-conical-potential-in-3-dimensions/297151#297151) over at physics.stackexchange.